# PHP: Scanning database for a certain value then organizing it

Tags: php, mysql

I have been working on this project and recently got stuck. Basically lets say I have a MySQL database and it has 2 columns, Name and Carrot. I want to scan a database and check each data entry whether that person likes carrots. If they like carrots the carrots entry should be 1 and if they don't it should be 0. If they do like carrots and want it to echo there name. How could I do this? I'm not very good with database things but this is sort of essential.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: This is real basic stuff. Please read and follow [a tutorial](http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65) first. Come back, if you have a specific question after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be a tad vague myself, as I don't know what all you have tried.

First, create a query to get a list of all people who like carrots:

```
SELECT `Name`, `Carrot` FROM MyTable WHERE `Carrot` = 1;
```

Next, execute that and get the results in PHP (web search this or ask, if you don't know how).

Then use a loop to go through each row of returned names and echo them out.

```
echo '$name likes carrots!';
```

I can't be more specific without more specific questions from you.

Comment: Thanks that pretty much exactly what i wanted. mainly the SELECT `Name`, `Carrot` FROM MyTable WHERE `Carrot` = 1; Thanks alot